# How to use splitters

Tags: c++, qt

I preprare example showing my investigation about splitters. I have 9 textEdits in mainWindow (without layout). I want create dynamic layout. It must be dynamic, because
a) User selects how many elements should be displayed.
b) I don't want use hide elements, because there remain their splitters.
c) I known how create static layout in QTDesigner

My problem is manual layout. In the future I need show for example first 2 textEdits. Then 4 texEdits etc...

This example have a problem that splitter5 is not in full Window size. MainWindow margins are not associated with splitter5.

Do you known where is a problem? 
Additionally, I'm not sure if this is even the right way. Maybe there are any other better solutions?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QGridLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSplitter *splitter1 = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);
    QSplitter *splitter2 = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);
    QSplitter *splitter3 = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);
    QSplitter *splitter4 = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);
    QSplitter *splitter5 = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical);


    splitter1->addWidget(ui->textEdit);
    splitter1->addWidget(ui->textEdit_2);
    splitter1->addWidget(ui->textEdit_3);

    splitter2->addWidget(ui->textEdit_4);
    splitter2->addWidget(ui->textEdit_5);
    splitter2->addWidget(ui->textEdit_6);

    splitter3->addWidget(ui->textEdit_7);
    splitter3->addWidget(ui->textEdit_8);
    splitter3->addWidget(ui->textEdit_9);

    splitter4->addWidget(splitter1);
    splitter4->addWidget(splitter2);

    splitter5->addWidget(splitter3);
    splitter5->addWidget(splitter4);

    this->layout()->addWidget(splitter5);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Problems are marked with an arrow
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
this->layout()->addWidget(splitter5);
```

You have to add the splitter to the central widget. (See [`QMainWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details)).

If you use only the splitter you can set it as central widget:

```
this->setCentralWidget(splitter5);
```

If you need more elements, create a container as central widget and add your own layout.